# httpd, vsftpd and the annoying selinux

Tags: httpd, centos6, selinux, ftp

I have a CentOS 6.3 installed with `httpd` running and `vsftpd` but I am unable to balance permission between the user able to upload over ftp and their website working.

What I do:

```
I create a user with their home directory as `/home/username` 
I create a sub folder called `html` for their website
I chown their directory `chown -R username:apache /home/username`
I chmod their directory `chmod -R 750 /home/username`
I chcon their directory `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /home/username`
```

and their website loads fine but they are unable to ftp, but if I do the following, they can ftp but their website doesnt load:

`chcon -R -t user_home_dir_t /home/username`

If I disable selinux, the user can ftp and the website loads. so what is the answer to keep selinux?

**EDIT**

Interestingly I followed Michael's comments below and just ran `restorecon` and it worked. But then I rebooted and now vsftp is fine and httpd can read fine, but httpd can not write.

This is my `ls -Z` response

`drwxr-x---. itmanx     apache     unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 itmanx`

These are the set booleans

```
allow_console_login                         on
allow_daemons_dump_core                     on
allow_daemons_use_tty                       on
allow_domain_fd_use                         on
allow_execmem                               on
allow_execmod                               on
allow_execstack                             on
allow_gssd_read_tmp                         on
allow_kerberos                              on
allow_mount_anyfile                         on
allow_nsplugin_execmem                      on
allow_postfix_local_write_mail_spool        on
allow_staff_exec_content                    on
allow_sysadm_exec_content                   on
allow_user_exec_content                     on
allow_zebra_write_config                    on
ftp_home_dir                                on
httpd_builtin_scripting                     on
httpd_can_network_connect_db                on
httpd_can_sendmail                          on
httpd_dbus_avahi                            on
httpd_enable_cgi                            on
httpd_enable_homedirs                       on
httpd_tty_comm                              on
httpd_unified                               on
init_upstart                                on
nscd_use_shm                                on
nsplugin_can_network                        on
openvpn_enable_homedirs                     on
privoxy_connect_any                         on
qemu_full_network                           on
qemu_use_cifs                               on
qemu_use_nfs                                on
qemu_use_usb                                on
sepgsql_enable_users_ddl                    on
sepgsql_unconfined_dbadm                    on
spamd_enable_home_dirs                      on
squid_connect_any                           on
unconfined_login                            on
use_nfs_home_dirs                           on
user_direct_dri                             on
user_ping                                   on
user_rw_noexattrfile                        on
user_setrlimit                              on
virt_use_sysfs                              on
virt_use_usb                                on
xguest_connect_network                      on
xguest_mount_media                          on
xguest_use_bluetooth                        on
```

**AUDIT LOG**

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111166.254:3204): arch=40000003 syscall=4 success=yes exit=2 a0=1 a1=b778e000 a2=2 a3=2 items=0 ppid=4114 pid=4119 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=96 comm="bash" exe="/bin/bash" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.584:3205): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.584:3205): arch=40000003 syscall=10 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5ef0e64 a1=3234 a2=b776cad8 a3=b5ef0e64 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.584:3206): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.584:3206): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6fcfc a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6fcfc items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.586:3207): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.586:3207): arch=40000003 syscall=10 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5ef0e64 a1=3234 a2=b776cad8 a3=b5ef0e64 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.586:3208): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.586:3208): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6b9a0 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6b9a0 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.586:3209): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.586:3209): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5f05f5c a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=b5f05f5c items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.587:3210): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.587:3210): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6d9d0 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6d9d0 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.587:3211): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.587:3211): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6d9d0 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6d9d0 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.587:3212): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.587:3212): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6d9d0 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6d9d0 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.588:3213): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.588:3213): arch=40000003 syscall=10 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5ef0e64 a1=3430 a2=b776cad8 a3=b5ef0e64 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.588:3214): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.588:3214): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6d9d0 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6d9d0 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.592:3215): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.592:3215): arch=40000003 syscall=10 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5ef0e64 a1=3234 a2=b776cad8 a3=b5ef0e64 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.592:3216): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.592:3216): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6af14 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6af14 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.593:3217): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.593:3217): arch=40000003 syscall=10 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5ef0e64 a1=3234 a2=b776cad8 a3=b5ef0e64 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.593:3218): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev=dm-2 ino=11012903 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.593:3218): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5e6aaf0 a1=442 a2=1b6 a3=b5e6aaf0 items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1350111180.594:3219): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=2376 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev=dm-2 ino=11012856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1350111180.594:3219): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=b5f05f5c a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=b5f05f5c items=0 ppid=2372 pid=2376 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Comment: Ive been told to create a new selinux context to accomodate both but i have no idea how...

Answer (score 2):

None of the above.

You [set the SELinux booleans](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Booleans.html) which allow httpd and vsftpd to access user home directories.

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

And after all your messing around, you probably should fix the messed up security contexts:

```
restorecon -r -v /home
```

Comment: Awesome!  In fact I only ran the restorecon command and now it's working :) :) STAR! Thank you

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I rebooted the server and same thing. I can still ftp, but cant write to the server from httpd. Can read ok though. (ps. both of those booleans are on)

Comment: Now fix the user permissions on the directory.

Comment: As in run `restorecon -r -v /home`? Just tried and no joy http://isis.dev.itmanx.com/

Comment: No, as in `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: Permissions are fine, I even tried chmod 777. It only ever works if i disable selinux `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`

Comment: OK, then you need to post the AVC denial messages from the log `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: Hi Michael.  I have included some of the AVC's in my original post above.

Comment: The interesting thing is this is a a brand new installation and I have done little to it apart from setup apache and create user accounts so I cant understand why this isnt a common problem.

Comment: Each AVC message has a corresponding "SYSCALL" log entry, and you omitted those. Please post ALL relevant information when asking your question.

Comment: Sorry dude. New to linux. Didn't know!

Comment: This is nearly right, but had to mark down, this wont work for `~/html` paths, only `~/public_html` paths.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I checked on an EL6 box... your answer IS right. Wont let me rescore this though..